# How should I prepare for Hardmode?

Tags: terraria

So I have never actually even tried to go into Hardmode yet, for the simple reason that I've never truly felt fully prepared for the challenges that await me once I enter the Hardmode World...coupled with nostalgia for my old world, but setting that aside...

What should a player have before they enter Hardmode?  How much of the map should be explored before they enact this permanent map change?  What essential resources should the player concern themselves with preserving before the transformation?

In short, how should I prepare for Hardmore?

**Important Note** - I do not need help preparing for the Wall of Flesh.  I already know that I need a battle platform stretching the length of Hell and I have the gear to fight it, I am more worried about preparing the entire rest of my world.

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Getting_Started_With_Hardmode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 things happen when you go to hard more:

1. stronger enemies and bosses appear.
2. Corruption/crimson spreads quicker
3. Hallow biomes appear and spread.

To prep for stronger enemies/bosses, you should make sure you have top tier pre-hardmode weapons/armor/accessories and 400 max health. ie: Molten armor and a strong weapon like nights edge.

Getting a surface mushroom biome with a house for the Truffle NPC and then buying a mushroom spear as soon as he moves in after hardmode will make surviving much easier. The spear has decent knockback, good damage, and can hit enemies through walls.

You should get a Molten pickaxe to make Colbalt/Pallidium mining possible early on. quickly breaking Demon Alters and raising yourself to at least oricalcum armor quickly will make the common enemies much more bearable.

If you care about the lose of your natural biomes then the spread of corruption/hallow is a problem. You cannot control where it spawns but you can harvest the biomes blocks and create artificial biomes later on. However, I think waiting until you can get the Steampunker NPC and can buy the Clentaminator to remove hallow/corruption is a better use of time.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to prepare for hard-mode. Note, all of these are actually optional, but the more you actually get done before going to hard-mode, the easier you will have it when in hard-mode.

1. Build a full Molten Set. Tools, Weapons, Armor. You need the molten pick-axe to mine the new ore you will be seeing in hard-mode.
2. All that weird equipment you have been hoarding that are also "Materials" - get them sorted. You will be able to combine these pretty early.
3. Quarantine your Corruption / Crimson sites by digging a 4-block wide trench around the entire thing. Line the top or bottom with a non-corruptible material like Wood. This will help you preserve important biomes like the Desert and the Jungle.
4. Get your home base super secured. Elevate it, and break it into manageable sections.
5. Build a sky bridge.
6. Build a dedicated battle arena for bosses.

Comment: When you say "a 4-block wide trench around the entire thing", what does that actually mean? Is it a trench on the surface only (what a "trench" would look like in real life), or a 4-wide vertical tunnel down each side?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I believe he means a 4 wide empty space surrounding the entire biome, so the second option if it extends all the way to the bottom of the map.

Comment: Correct, by "trench" I mean a square, actually, surrounding the entire corrupted area. Alternately you can dig two vertical shafts all the way down that are 4 blocks wide. Note: This will only stop the corruption that is there before Hard-Mode starts! Massive spikes of corruption / crimson  are generated when you start hard-mode, and every time you smash an alter you get new ore placed in the world, but more corruption as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add something else that was added recently, Fishing.

Fishing can give you a great boost when entering hardmode if you save up the crates you get while fishing pre-hardmode. That is because when you enter hardmode and open the crates, there is a chance of acquiring the hard mode ores.

When I entered hardmode I could make an entire set of Adamantite and Titanium armor.

This allows you to stand a chance against everything as you're normally incredibly weak to everything right after starting hard mode. Acquiring these ores through fishing instead of by breaking the orbs/hearts and mining them means that the spread of corruption/crimson will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Let me state the obvious first: It will get MUCH harder! A lot of new enemies will spawn that will provide A LOT of damage.

**My advice?**

Build up your defense points. Because coming from normal mode with weapons that provide a lot of damage won't matter since the new enemies will have much more health/damage resistence then you do.

Also, if you're more of a head-on type of person (which I was), and don't prefer to dodge attacks. **STOP THAT IMMEDIATELY**. You must learn to dodge as soon as you possibly can, or else hardmode will consume you.

But don't take my word for it. You should use whatever strategy you prefer to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Have a full set of Crimson Armor. While you will sacrifice some defense, you will gain life regeneration. Molten tools are necessary to mine the new ores. Put deep pits of lava around your house to kill invaders. Definitely break demon alters to get hard mode ores.

Answer (score 0):

first have full molten armor and tools i recommenced getting the Nights-edge beacuse u can craft it into the terra blade also havr the mini shark handy as well as the demon scythe. be sure to put lave pits or elevate your house and SORT YOUR CHESTS it will help soooooooo much.

Answer (score -1):

You should get yourself some strong weapons.

If you are a mage type, Demon Scythe and Night's Edge are good options for a spell and a reliable melee weapon.  You'll need the Night's Edge anyway to craft the Terra Blade, which will be a very good melee weapon to craft once you're in Hardmode.

I also recommend getting the MiniShark before going into Hardmode, as it's a very reliable weapon, though it'll cost you 35 gold from the Gunsmith.  You can upgrade it once you get to Hardmode into a Megashark, whih is a very good ranged weapon for this mode.